# Compare string with regular expression on an expect script

Tags: regex, expect

I am trying to do a simple comparison in my expect script using regex. But, its not working for some reason.

```
if { $loadNum == {[0-9]+} } {
  Do something
} else {
  Exit
}
```

loadNum is an input which I get from user and I just want to make sure its just a number.
But, with the above script, its always going to else case.

Could you please help me in finding what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you compare string with regex? I think you should use command "regexp".

```
if {[regexp {[0-9]+} $loadNum]} {
  Do something
} else {
  Exit
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if your string *contains* a digit:

```
if {[regexp {\d} $loadNum]}
# or
if {[string match {[0-9]} $loadNum]}
```

If you want to check if your string is *only* digits, pick one of

```
if {[regexp {^\d+$} $loadNum]}
if {![regexp {\D} $loadNum]}
if {![string match {[^0-9]} $loadNum]}
```